# Механизм обмена данными приложения с сервером

Tags: https, websocket, rsa, aes

Третью неделю пишу мессенджер под андроид. Сейчас переделываю протокол с обычного HTTP + JSON на новый: HTTPS + Websockets + JSON.

1. На мой взгляд HTTPS + Websockets + JSON близок к идеальному решению и лучше уже не сделать. Или я что-то упускаю? Хотелось бы определиться с конечной версией сейчас, чтобы в будущем не переделывать протокол снова.
2. В каком виде передавать токен сессии? Была идея завернуть его в RSA контейнер, но так его как и текстовый украдут и пришлют на сервер. Ну не сможет злоумышленник узнать что в нем, ну и не надо, а сервер будет понапрасну тратить мегагерцы. Выходит токен должен быть простой текстовой строкой и без вариантов? Ну может в AES завернуть, он достаточно шустрый.

UPD: Эта связка протоколов выбрана по тому, что они быстрые, логичные, не имеют избыточности. Так же websocket хорошо дополняет json, так как в последнем нет четкого указания на длину, а в websocket есть. К слову, json будет заменен новым протоколом, который сейчас разрабатывается.

Answer (score 1):

для секретности есть wss, шифрованный канал. как вариант можно использовать проверенные методы авторизации по https. по id сессии привязать и сеанс wss.
у меня так работает. при попытке стороннего подключения по wss ничего не произойдет, т.к. подключение wss не подтверждается  наличием id сессии https.
реализация несколько сложнее, но суть такая. вообще использование json несколько излишне. т.к. добавляет дополнительные данные. в принципе информационные данные можно разделять определёнными символами, на приёмной стороне использовать оператор split. в ws длина может быть не ограничена.